# Cannot store or retreive documents from firestore via python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store a json document into firestore and am using `firebase-admin` package for python.

Whenever i run my file `py firebase.py` it just stucks and doesn't do anything and then request gets timedout

this is the code

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("fir-firebase-97d4b-firebase-adminsdk-uv2gq-e03ebce9ac.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

ref = db.collection(u'demo').document(u'hello')
ref.set({
    'first': 'demo-name'
})

print('done')
```

python version is `3.8`
firebase-admin version is `5.2.0`

Comment: Have you set the proper rules?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes i have, and as a matter of fact, i tried the exact same code in google collab and it worked, just doesn't work on my local machine